# How to read text file in python after that write something on same file

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am currently working with yolov5 code is [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) i slightly modified in code to save results in text file called **output.txt**

output.txt file :

```
0: 480x640 2 persons, 1 tv, 1: 480x640 5 persons, 1 cell phone, Done. (0.759s) Mon, 04 April 11:39:48
0: 480x640 2 persons, 1 laptop, 1: 480x640 4 persons, 1 oven, Done. (0.763s) Mon, 04 April 11:39:50
```

After that , i wanna validate text file line by line with following conditions

```
if person and tv detected in same row add status : High 
if person and laptop detected in same row add status : Low
```

Expected output :

```
0: 480x640 2 persons, 1 tv, 1: 480x640 5 persons, 1 cell phone, Done. (0.759s) Mon, 04 April 11:39:48 status : High 
0: 480x640 2 persons, 1 laptop, 1: 480x640 4 persons, 1 oven, Done. (0.763s) Mon, 04 April 11:39:50 status : Low
```

Is it possible if yes how can i resolve that

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code may help you.

```py
with open('result.txt','r') as file:
    data = file.readlines() # return list of all the lines in the text file.

for a in range(len(data)): # loop through all the lines.
    line = data[a]
    if 'person' in line and 'tv' in line: # Check if person and tv in the same line.
        data[a] = line.replace('\n','') + ' status : High\n'
    elif 'person' in line and 'laptop' in line:# Check if person and laptop in the same line.
        data[a] = line + ' status : Low\n'

with open('result.txt','w') as file: 
    file.writelines(data) # write lines to the file.
```